# NSRange giving nonsensical location

Tags: ios, nsstring

I'm experiencing this weird effect where calling location on rangeOfString is returning a very large value when it shouldn't...

my code looks like this:

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:subString];
NSLog(@"range is %@", NSStringFromRange(range));
```

this logs out to `range is {2147483647, 0}`

Can't figure out why exactly.

Some things that might be causing this:

- The substring is generated from an array of bytes using NSString's
  initWithBytes method
- The substring tells me its an NSCFString * but also says 'variable is
  not NSString'
- the substring logs in the console as expected

any help greatly appreciated

here is somethign that is striking me as weird:

[image]

Comment: That number is `NSNotFound`, it's not nonsensical at all - it meant the substring wasn't found. What are the two strings?

Comment: Interesting, but the issue remains. If I log out the subString, i find that it prints perfectly in the console, in other words, that what is printed in the console is contained within 'string.'

Comment: You need to post the code that shows how the string and substring are created and subsequently processed. There are no extra points for making people guess.  :-)

Comment: @SeanDanzeiser can you post example strings? There must be a subtle difference somewhere.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That just means that your substring is not present in your string, do the following to verify this:

```
NSRange range = [string rangeOfString:subString];
if (range.location == NSNotFound) {
  NSLog(@"String not found");
} else {
  NSLog(@"range is %@", NSStringFromRange(range));
}
```

Comment: ya but the thing is the substring logs out a string that IS contained within the other string, thats why i am confused. In other words, it should be returning true

Comment: Can you post the strings? Are they variable or specific ones? Because I just did a short test for this and that number is in fact NSNotFound, so we need a bigger picture here.

Comment: also, the string's class is not NSString when I log out the class, its returning __NSCFString

Comment: This is because NSString is a class cluster.

Comment: cool thanks for the info. unfortunately that doesnt solve the problem tho

Comment: Post the code where you create the string, you're problem is extremely odd. There shouldn't be a problem creating the string from bytes.

Comment: Ya turns out i had a couple of dead bytes in there at the end. thanks guys!